# Caching API response from simple ruby script

Tags: json, ruby, api

I'm working on a simple ruby script with cli that will allow me to browse certain statistics inside the terminal.

I'm using API from the following website: https://worldcup.sfg.io/matches

```
require 'httparty'

url = "https://worldcup.sfg.io/matches"

response = HTTParty.get(url)
```

I have to goals in mind. First is to somehow save the JSON response (I'm not using a database) so I can avoid unnecessary requests. Second is to check if the new data is available, and if it is, to override the previously saved response.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... with cli ...

So caching in memory is likely not available to you. In this case you can save the response to a file on disk.

> Second is to check if the new data is available, and if it is, to override the previously saved response.

The thing is, how can you check if new data is available without doing a request for the data? Not possible (given the information you provided). So you can simply keep fetching data every 5 minutes or so and updating your local file.

Comment: I phrased it very badly. Is there a way not to blast the API with requests each time I'm using the script and making sure it's up to date? My first idea is to only make an actual request to check if new data is available after certain amount of time (Eg if request is made after 24 hours, check if new data is available)

Comment: @Lotix No, your phrasing was ok. This _is_ caching. You simply need to store timestamp of last request alongside the response. So when you need the data, you first go to the cache and check if the data is "fresh" enough. If it is, read the file from disk and return. If it's not, fetch new data, update timestamp and the file with response.

Comment: @Lotix: if you were asking "is there a magical switch/option?", then no. You likely will have to code this caching logic by yourself.